Machine A configure a static arp When a ping msg with right mac address but wrong ip address from machine B. Does machine A give ping response?

Machine A arp list such as ip1:MAC1, ip2:MAC2;
Machine b know ip and mac  of machine A. But machine b configure mac1 and ip2 for itself.
When Machine b send a ping msg to A. Does A give a response?


If the answer helped you, you should accept it so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

No. Do not confuse layer-2 (MAC) addressing with layer-3 (IP addressing. Each network layer is independent of the others. ICMP (ping) is an integral part of IP, and the IP process will not respond to any packets not addressed to it.
Even if the data-link protocol accepts a frame with the correct MAC address, the network protocol (IP) will not use it because it is not addressed to it. It is the IP process that would need to use its ICMP to respond to an IMCP echo request, and it will not if it is not addressed to it.


Sorry， my title discription is wrong. Actually I want to ask, if
machine B configure ip1 and mac2 as it‘s address. But this combination
(ip1 with mac2) is not in machine A's ARP list. Then when B try to
ping a, does A give a response?

Host A will respond to a ping to IP address 2 using MAC address 2, and Host B, configured with MAC address 1 will drop a frame with MAC address 2, never sending it to the IP process. That is like me calling you will a fake caller ID, you missing the call and trying to call me back with the faked phone number.

If machine B tries to send an IP packet to machine A it uses A's IP address. Since that is also used as a local address for B itself, B doesn't actually try to send the packet through the network but evaluates it locally. Since it's a ping it replies to that ping itself.

Does A give a response?

No. A doesn't even get the echo request from B.
Networks rely on unambiguous addressing. You can't use the same IP address or MAC address on multiple hosts without messing up the network.
